# IntentService connected to Server listening

Tags: android, service, android-service, intentservice

I coded an IntentService where I send a command line. Is related to an activity where I'm trying to program a Console. The activity's purpose is to do a 'command prompt' where I can send and receive to/from the server.

The Service's action is:

1. COnnect to the server
2. Send command line
3. Get response
4. Retrieve response to user

The main problem is that every time I send a command line, the Service has to reconnect to the server. (Cause every time I'm starting the whole Service)*How can I avoid this step?*

I would like to "keep alive" the service waiting for a command line to send, without the need of reconnect every time I execute its action.

Is there any way to do it action-responsive? I mean, I start the service and every time I set its action (setAction) and put the line I want (putExtra). Then I have to start the service again?

Good night. Tomorrow I'll be back :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to its "one shot" design, using an `IntentService` isn't a good approach IMO.

If you don't want to start the service each time you send a command, then I'd suggest you 'bind' to a standard `Service` (see [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)). If you bind to the `Service` in your `Activity`'s `onResume()` method and unbind in `onPause()` your `Activity` will be able to directly call methods in the `Service`.

You will, of course, have to create your own worker `Thread` in your `Service` to handle any work involving your network connection however. If you want any tips on how to do that, look at the [source code for IntentService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) - it's fairly straight-forward.

Comment: So now I'm working on it. I bounded a `Service`, and now I want to implement a method on the service which communicates to the server every second (for example) to get some data. I just did a timed task on the main activity which launches `service.getServerData()`. **But will the  Service connection-to-the-server keep alive between every call?**

Comment: @Thorba : That all depends on your connection. You need to set 'keep-alive' on your connection and it will also depend on if your server allows infinite connections. You're going to have to maintain your service connection object within the service and build in some logic to check if the connection / communication fails. If it does you'll need to reconnect before trying another attempt at communicating. I'd have thought communicating every second would usually keep a connection open but beware of what you might be doing to the battery on the Android device - that's heavy network use.

Comment: Okay. Im now testing about keeping connection objects created on the `onBind` method (I mean sockets). I know it's a heavy work usage of the battery, but it is allowed in this project I have on mind :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an `IntentService`. Per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Instead, you should consider using a normal `Service` (calling [stopSelf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf())) when you want to stop the service (and your connection to the server). Or, if you'd like the connection to the server to have the same lifecycle as the activity, you can create a [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html): it will start when your activity binds to it and then stop when the last activity is unbound.